# Tomcat set a URL and load velocity VM file instead of index.html

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I want to load a VM file in the url `mysite.com/test/`. I've placed the `test.vm` in `/webapps/ROOT/test/`. But I'm getting 404 error. If I create a `index.html` then it works but I want to load a `test.vm`.

In Tomcat web.xml I've created the path.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>/application/myapp-web</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in `my-app-servlet.xml` I've also created a resolver.

```
<bean id="viewResolver-test"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use velocity inside Spring in the following way:

```
String template = ........;


Velocity.init();
VelocityContext velContext = new VelocityContext();

StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
            
Velocity.evaluate( velContext, w, "mystring", template);  
String html = w.toString();
```

where the string template is string containing the *.vm model. I normaly read the string from database but if you want to read a file you can put it under /src/main/resources and read it in the following way

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("path-inside-resources-dir.vm");
//Logic to move a stream contect into a String valiable
```

I hope it may help